# How to get Last document in Flutter from Firbase Firestore?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a chat App in Flutter with Firebase I need to get the user's last messages in the chat. I've already created chat collections. How do I get the last document and document filed value from Firebase Firestore? Your help is realy appericated. Thanks

Comment: We can't tell what you mean by "last document".  Collections in Firestore don't have an order other than what you define by way of fields that you use in documents.  Please edit the question to explain more clearly what you're trying to do and what you've done so far to try to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can add sendTime field and you can get last document like this.

```
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection(collectionName)
    .orderBy("sendTime", descending: true)
    .limit(1)
    .get();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but I'm not getting required result